# Jquery serialize to PHP array

Tags: php, jquery, serialization

I want to send the result of a HTML sorting to the server by serializing with jQuery.
This works if I only send the result:

```
var result = $(this).sortable('serialize');

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cms/update/',
    data: result,
});
```

But I try to send a Javascript Object to the server wich contains the serialized 'result'

In PHP I get an array with result_2 as the serialize object:

```
Array
(
    [ids_1] => miti_1_ti_2_col_2
    [article_id] => article_id_2
    [result_1] => 
    [ids_2] => miti_1_ti_2_col_1
    [result_2] => article_id[]=2
)
```

How can I get this result to be an array in PHP?

Comment: json good enough? php have json_decode/encode.

Comment: The easiest way would be to send your POST data in array format in the first place. In other words `ids[1]=miti_1_ti_2_col_2&ids[2]=miti_1_ti_2_col_1&...` etc.

Comment: I think this indeed is the easiest way to go, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood "result" is a serialized object too.

So you have to unserialize result at first.

Then you have to unserialize result2. Something like that:

```
$res1 = unserialize($data);
if (isset($res1['result_2']){
   $res2 = unserialize($res['result_2']);
}
```

### **Updated:**

I don't know if your result_2 in data is already serialized. Therefore here are two examples:

**if result_2 is not serialized in data:**

```
$arr = array('id_1' => 'miti_1_ti_2_col_2',
             'article_id' => 'article_id_2',
             'result_1' => '',
             'ids_2' => 'miti_1_ti_2_col_1'
            );

$arr['result_2'] = $arr;

$test1 = serialize($arr);
$test1 = unserialize($test1);
```

**If result_2 is already serialized in data:**

```
$arr = array('id_1' => 'miti_1_ti_2_col_2',
             'article_id' => 'article_id_2',
             'result_1' => '',
             'ids_2' => 'miti_1_ti_2_col_1'
            );

$arr['result_2'] = serialize($arr);

$test2 = serialize($arr);
$test2 = unserialize($test2);

$test2['result_2'] = unserialize($test2['result_2']);
```

This code works I checked out it. If your code still doesn't work check *result* in JS.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work: $res1 = unserialize($_POST);
  if (isset($res1['result_2'])){
      $res2 = unserialize($res1['result_2']);
  }
  
  print_r($res2);

Comment: The post is in the Question it's the array

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, you need to convert a string such as action[]=1&action[]=2 into an array?

If that is right you can use the following: (when $_POST["order"] = "action[]=1&action[]=2")

```
$result = preg_split("/&?action\[\]=/", $_POST["order"], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

This will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

Comment: To work with article_id use: `preg_split("/&?article\_id\[\]=/", $_POST["result_2"], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)`